# Keyup event only fires on first textarea

Tags: jquery

The `textarea` input and `button` are attached to all articles posted and from my database. Technically they are like a 'comment' and 'reply' box and button.

The problem is I apply a `keyup` function to the `textarea` so that if the `textarea` is empty the button remains deactivated. The `keyup` event only works on the first comment/reply `textarea`. If I use a `class` all the buttons in all comments get activated.

Please help, I hope I was clear enough with my plea.

```
<form>
  <textarea name="reply" class="reply" id="reply"  placeholder="React to this" required="required">
  <button id="btn" class="btn-reply" type="submit" disabled>Reply
</form>

<script>
  $('.reply').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val() <= 0) {
      $(".btn").attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $(".btn").attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`btn` is the `id` on the element so it will only ever work for the first one as `id` need to be unique in the DOM. You need to change that to a class.

Then you can use DOM traversal to find the `.btn-reply` related to the clicked button, like this:

```js
$('.reply').keyup(function() {
  $(this).next('.btn-reply').prop('disabled', $(this).val().trim().length == 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea name="reply" class="reply" id="reply" placeholder="React to this" required="required"></textarea>
  <button id="btn" class="btn-reply" type="submit" disabled>Reply</button>
</form>
```

A few other things to note here. Firstly, your HTML was invalid as you missed both the `textarea` and `button` closing tags. Secondly, you can negate the need for an `if` condition by providing a boolean value to `prop()` method.

Comment: Thanks @Rory McCrossan for your answer. I don't think you understand my error stricken question. the textarea element and button was while looped alongside each each articles. All posted articles from users were fetched and shown in html, at the bottom of each comments the form to reply is beneath each

Answer (score 0):

because you use class, all buttons with that class gets activated. Maybe try this:

```
$('.reply').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val()<=0){
        $(this).next().attr('disabled', true);
    }else{
        $(this).next().attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

See working **[example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jvwVJq)**

ID's should be unique, so don't use id="btn" for every button, you can better remove it.
Your html was not valid, so I changed that in the example. Maybe copy-paste error